# How can I tell whether a binary can be run in the terminal or requires X Window System on Linux without access to the Internet?

Tags: linux

If I would like to know whether a binary can be run from the command line, X Window System or both, how do I tell without access to the Internet?

Comment: Wait...are you asking how to find out if the binary does utilize a GUI of any sorts?

Comment: @Bobby - I am asking if a binary requires the use of a desktop environment or X Window System to run and if so how do I tell apart from the obvious use of a prefix e.g. gedit

Comment: Use `ldd` on the executable.

Comment: @David Schwartz - Do you mean `ldd vim`?

Comment: Rather `ldd $(which vim)` I'd say.

Comment: @Eroen - How would I be able to run the commmand `ldd` say against the entire `/bin, `/sbin, /usr/bin and /usr/sbin` directories?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: `for file in /bin/* /sbin/* ...; do ldd "$file"; done` or `find /bin /sbin ... -type f -executable -exec ldd {} \;` or ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ldd` to check whether it is linked against an X11 library such as `libX11` or `libxcb`. If either is listed, the program *may* use X11.

However, it does not mean it *requires* X11; this is impossible to determine programmatically without either examining source code or running the program. For example, a program may display a graphical window if X11 is available, and a text interface otherwise.

If the executable is statically-linked, run `strings` on it and look for the words "`DISPLAY`", "`.Xauthority`", "`/tmp/.X`" or similar. This is an even less reliable indicator, since these strings might occassionally occur even in purely textual programs.

Comment: +1. Although it doesn't do everything in the question, I don't think a better solution exists unless sources are available.

Comment: @grawity - What do you mean by statically-linked?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: One that has library functions [copied to the executable itself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_linking) instead of just referencing them through `/usr/lib/*.so` files.

Answer (score 1):

Read the man page.

Though you may actually have to ***read*** the fool thing rather than glancing at the usage and quickly paging through the options.